# What are best practices for creating a system account? (*NIX)

Tags: best-practices, service-accounts

I've manually installed a service called Gate One into `/opt`. I want to harden its security, so I thought I'd create a system account for it to use, because of least necessary privileges, and all that.

However, when I ran `adduser --system gateone`, it created a home directory, which I didn't really want. Therefore, I ran `adduser --system --home-dir /opt/gateone gateone`, because I'd seen some system accounts setting home directories pertaining to them. However, this made the login shell `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/false`, which it had done the first time (when I didn't specify a home directory). I'm a bit confused now on what I should set these fields as.

**tl;dr:** when creating a system account on a *NIX operating system, what are the best practices for setting the home directory, the login shell, and anything else that's relevant? Why?

<sub>Note: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 Raring, if it matters, since IIRC `adduser` can vary quite a bit distribution-to-distribution.</sub>

Comment: 1) Don't use frontends to `useradd` if you don't want them making decisions for you. 2) Explicitly set any account details that you don't want defaults being assumed for.

Comment: I have the thing running as "nobody" with group "nogroup".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't really a specific best practice, except that the shell should be /bin/false unless a shell is needed, the password hash should be `!` unless the user is expected to log in, a descriptive name should be given, and a home directory should be set to `/dev/null` or similar if the application doesn't require a valid home directory.  The user should have its own group, preferably in the system ID range; if it doesn't require a primary GID of root, for instance, don't give it one, and certainly don't give it users without a specific requirement.  It all depends.  Specify everything you care about (see `man adduser` for all the available options).

Comment: That covers most of my hit list. As a general rule it should also have a dedicated group (e.g. if the user is `bind` there should be a group `bind` with a matching ID), and the UID/GID should be within your OS's "system UID range" (typically < 1000).

Comment: Good catch.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install application the best choice is to make a package for that system and follow admin guideline for that system (in guides there is written how to install, where, how to integrate app with system and so on). As you are using Ubuntu you can follow Ubuntu/Debian guide. It may be time-consuming at first, but if you deploy it often (often upgrades) or on several machines it will helps you.

`adduser` command has switches to set up what are you asking for. Use `adduser --help`. Basically you can write `adduser --system --home /var/lib/my_app --shell /bin/false --disable-login --disable-password`. Note that most of system services has home directories in /var/lib/ or if you not provide a package for a system it probably should be as you wrote in `/opt/<service>`

Comment: I'm aware of the switches and how to use them. I'm asking what the best practices for the values are.

Comment: There is no general rule. You adapt it to the system. According to Ubuntu or Debian I wrote what I would do: home=/var/lib/<service> and shell=/bin/false. You have to look at the manual for details.